# Hibernate JPA - Make Unique constraint but ignore null or empty

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any annotation or setting to which I can make a set of columns unique but ignore that constraint if null or empty. For example,

saleId
itemNumber

I want these two items to be unique, but the itemNumber can have all nulls until itemNumbers are assigned later. Other than a programmatic solution, is there a way to enforce this constraint using JPA/Hibernate?